# Copy Multiple Columns and Paste into same column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a dynamic range of O5:O60, P5:P60, etc. into I5:I60.

I set up is a separate loop, but I need each column from O to YM one-by-one/separately to be entered into column I where I paste each output to the right open cell.

I have around 1000 columns of inputs (column O to column YM same range 5:60)

I tried:

```vb
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 1000
    Range("O" & i).Copy Range("O5:O60")
    Range("I5:I60").PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteValues
Next i
```

I see the code cut instead of copy the input column "O".

I have worked to this, still not working.

```vb
Dim startcolumn as integer
Set startcolumn = 15

Dim startrow as integer
set startrow = 5

Dim endrow as integer
Set endrow = 60

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs")
    Dim inputrange As Excel.Range
    Set inputrange = .Cells(startrow, startcolumn).Offset(endrow - startrow,0)
    inputrange.Copy
    Sheets("Inputs").Range("I5:I60").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
If startcolumn >= 650 Then
    ExitSub
End If
```

Comment: It's more like 649 columns. Could you accurately explain where the values need to be copied? If you want to copy to `I5:I60`, the data won't fit and you might as well write `Range(I5:I60).Value = Range(YM5:YM60).Value`. Do you maybe want to write the column values one below the other in column `I`, populating the range `I5:I36348`? Please do clarify by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74037228/edit) at any time.

Comment: Your question is still not clear, unfortunately. If all the columns from `O5:O60` to `YM5:YM60` are copied to `I5:I60`, then you'll only ever see the last data from `YM` in column `I`. If you want the destination column to increment from `I` to `J` to `K` etc., then you'll overwrite column `O` when you get to it. Is the source data worksheet different from the destination worksheet, or are they the same?

Comment: Thanks! I will try to clarify. I am trying to copy 1000+ columns of data that is stored in columns O to YM one by one. Each column (O5 to YM60) represents an input that then flows into column I, from there column I that produces outputs that I copy and paste to other sheets. This code I have working fine. I just need help creating the loop of going one by one for each column from column O to column YM, that copy and pastes each column one by one into column I. This is all being done on the same sheet.

Comment: You need to copy the new code to [your post (your question)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74037228/edit) and delete your new post in the answers section. The line `Set inputrange = .Cells(startrow, startcolumn).Offset(endrow - startrow,0)` references the cell `O60`. So you're copying the value in cell `O60` to all the cells in the range `I5:I60`. That's not a very helpful explanation. You gotta try harder. Why don't you share the *This code I have working fine*-code. That could be useful.

Comment: I would like to run like so: Column O cells 5:60 pasted in Column I ----> Column P cells 5:60 pasted in Column I ------> Column Q cells 5:60 pasted into Column  I, ... all the way until column YM. It is always the same paste range, just different copy range that moves right to left.

Comment: Apologies Left to Right

Comment: So what's wrong with my posted answer? It does exactly what you're describing. Just replace `ActiveSheet` with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs")` and you're good to go. The *Paste* range is `drg`, the *Copy* range is `srg`. Each of the *Copy* columns is `scrg`.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Columns of a Range

```
Sub LoopColumns()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("O5:YM60")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range("I5:I60")

    Dim scrg As Range
    
    For Each scrg In srg.Columns
        
        drg.Value = scrg.Value
        
        ' do your stuff here using 'drg'
    
    Next scrg

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried to share a better attempt above as a post to what I am trying to do